# Has and belongs to many add in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

If I have this relationship how would I add to my view so that when I create a student I am given a textbox where I can add multiple courses for the new student?

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end


<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name%><br />

    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %><br />

    <%= f.submit %><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you creating new courses in the form, or just creating associations to existing courses?

Comment: I want to create new courses in the form if they dont exist in the db yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend refactoring your models as follows:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, :through => :enrollments
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
end
```

and using RyanB's `nested_form` gem: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: Would my Enrollment model then just have student_id and course_id fields?

Comment: Yep. `has_many :through` is nearly as easy and far more flexible than `has_and_belongs_to_many`. You only need those two fields, but you can add anything else you might find useful. I've found that there's seldom a reason to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the awesome [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) series from Railscasts.

Answer (score 0):

<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>

```
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name%><br />

<%= f.label :description %><br />
<%= f.text_field :description %><br />
<%= f.fields_for :courses do |cf| %>
   ....course attributes
<% end %>
<%= f.submit %><br />
```

<% end %>

In your controller action:
  @student.courses.build 
this will create one course

or n.times do
  @student.courses.build
end

will add n courses to student object